# Rails 'possible_controllers' problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What I'm trying to do is pretty simple: generate a list of permissions based on controllers action defined roles.

This works pretty nicely, the only problem, is that when I try to generate the list of rails controllers a second time (note: the first time works flawlessly) using:

```
ActionController::Routing.possible_controllers
```

I get an array of current controller classes instead of strings, like I would get the first time, needless to say, this breaks my code by generating an exception.

Why does this method act differently on multiple calls ? Is it something I'm missing, or a ruby/rails bug ? (I'm running on windows)

The temporary fix: I store the resulted string array in the session so the next time I retrieve the list from there without calling again the possible_controllers method.

But when a user logs off and a new one logs in the problem reappears, which will not work for production, meaning I would need to take it off.

Comment: I created a dummy rails project and issued the call you mention in the console. I consistently get an array of strings. I'm using Ruby 1.8.7 and Rails 2.3.5 on Linux. It's not a solution but it might help point in the right direction.

Comment: I get the same stuff in the console. I shall try to deploy it on a linux host, maybe its platform depedent

Answer (score 0):

The docs say it should return an array. So i suggest you write your code to work with the array version and then insert a dummy call to get rid of the string version, you might also have found a bug, if you have please report it.